# Only 1st of n external CSS file is loaded in Chrome and IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a weird issue and couldn't find the reason from web.

Issue is: With the below codes, reset.css works but following 2 css files doesn't work.

If I delete reset.cc, the second css works. If I delete first 2, then last one works.

As a summary, somehow only 1st of n external CSS file is loaded in Chrome and IE. This is my work computer. I am not an admin in this computer. I worked in custom 'my documents/web' folder. Also I created all html and css from scratch except reset.css.

I am sure that all files are loaded. And sure that this is not a cache issue. I made my work in local folder environment.

Chrome version: 25.0.1364.172

IE version: 9

My external css order:

1. reset.css
2. fixed.css
3. responsive.css

You already know reset.css. the other two are:

**fixed.css**

```
body{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

**responsive.css**

```
body{
font-size:300%;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>  
    <script src="js/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script><!-- this is the javascript allowing html5 to run in older browsers -->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" media="screen" title="html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fixed.css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet for X resolution" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet for different viewport widths" />
</head>
<body id="page">
<div id="wrapper-header">a</div><!-- header wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper-content">b</div><!-- content wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper-footer">c</div><!-- footer wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

## EDIT

As you it's weird in Chrome inspector? I am 1 step closer to the issue, but what is it specifically?

[image]

Comment: Check your browser debugger (Firebug, or Chrome developer tools), Go to the `NET` tab, and double check that it's actually loading those files.

Comment: I am sure that in each case 1st css file is loaded. Also I don't have any external CSS linking problem.

Comment: Do you see each of those `link` elements in the DOM inspector? Have you validated your HTML code?

Comment: yes W3C validator says both html5 and css are valid

Comment: Oops! I have some issue with Chrome inspector. I'll edit my Q and put the image after 2 mins.

Comment: The head is collapsed so I can't see if the scripts are there or not. There is nothing weird with your screenshot, it looks perfectly fine to me.  
If you mean the classes on the html element, that's Modernizr's work.

Comment: You're right I think also, I deleted Modernizr.js but issue still exists. thanks